# How to resolve error No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'm new in MongoDB and I want to implement sharding in MongoDB, I have some errors and I don't find a concrete answer on how to resolve. I execute these commands to start 3 different servers on different ports, by default mongo is set on port 27017.

```
start mongod --replSet s1 --logpath \data\rs1\1.Log --dbpath \data\rs1 --port 27017 -- smallfiles --oplogsize64
start mongod --replSet s1 --logpath \data\rs2\2.Log --dbpath \data\rs2 --port 27018 -- smallfiles --oplogsize64
start mongod --replSet s1 --logpath \data\rs3\3.Log --dbpath \data\rs3 --port 27019 -- smallfiles --oplogsize64
```

Now then I try to start a server for example
`mongo --port 27017` is starting, but

`mongo --port 27018`
`mongo --port 27019`

I have this error:

```
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27018, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27018 :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

Or if I config further:

```
config={_id:"s1",members:[
{_id:0,host:"localhost:37017"},
{_id:1,host:"localhost:37018"},
{_id:2,host:"localhost:37019"}]};
rs.initiate(config);
```

The next error is

```
"ok" : 0,
        "errmsg": "This node was not started with the replSet option",
        "code" : 76,
        "codeName" : "NoReplicationEnabled"
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What mongo db version are u using? I'd try adding the --bindIp option set to localhost on the connection command. **Also,** you have an extra space before `--smallfile`

Comment: A sharded cluster has at least 3 host, the **Config** ReplicaSet, the **Shard Replica Sets** and the mongos **Router**. Maybe you mixed them up. Follow this tutorial: [Deploy a Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/) If you follow it carefully step-by-step then it should work.

Comment: Option `smallfile` belongs to storage engine MMAPv1 which has been removed already in Mongo v4.2 - you should not use it.

Comment: Maybe start with an un-sharded Replica Set: [Deploy a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/). Once you succeed with a simple Replica Set you can evolve to the sharded cluster. The **Config Server** and the **Shards** are always Replica Sets.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. I'd follow this troubleshooting steps:

1. fix the connection options: there is an extra space before `smallfiles`
2. try binding the Ip to localhost (I believe this is more important for older versions <3.6). this is done adding `--bind_ip localhost` on each command.
3. check out the log files, there should be an error log right in there.

*If it is not enough, include your mongo version, OS and the output from the log files.*